# JavaScript calculating time difference function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function

---

Here when I press the button "Check for Due" it doesn't redirect me to the alert() function. Any suggestion to fix the error?

```html
<form name = "myForm" method = "POST" action = "form.html">

  <table>

    <tr>
      <td> Book Returning Due Date:  </td>
      <td><input type = "date" name = "due_date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" id = "dueDate" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Current Date:  </td>
      <td><input type = "date" name = "current_date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" id = "currentDate" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class = "button-1" type="button" name = "due_fine" value = "Check for Due" onclick = "Fine();" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input class = "button-2" type = "reset" value = "Reset">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
<script>
  function Fine()
  {
    var currentDate = new Date(document.getElementById("currentDate").value);
    var dueDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dueDate").value);
    var z = parseInt((currentDate - dueDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

    alert("overdue by:" z "days");
  }
</script>
```

Here when I press the button "Check for Due" it doesn't redirect me to the alert() function. Any suggestion to fix the error?

Comment: Look at the error message in your browser's console. It'll show which line the error is in. I guess the alert statement.

Comment: alert("overdue by:" +  z +  "days"); Syntax error

Comment: Thanks @mr-geek, nikola-lukic, m69 :) All your suggestions helped me to fix the code! Thanks again!

Comment: Use console instead of alert. It's much more versatile.

Also it's widely considered best practice to *not* embed event handlers inside your HTML. Try this instead:

`document.querySelector('input[name=due_fine]').onclick = Fine`

Comment: I've just started learning JavaScript and there's alot more to improve. Thanks for the suggestion @skylize :)

Comment: Happy to help @hash_hw. That single line of code I wrote for you is pretty dense for a newbie. A few things to look into so you can understand it better: [Intro to Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events), [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [CSS Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Your alert text is incorrect. It should be `"overdue by: " + z + "days"`.
Also, you can use [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Using template string, your string message should be `overdue by:  ${z} days`

```js
function Fine(){
  var currentDate = new Date(document.getElementById("currentDate").value);
  var dueDate = new Date(document.getElementById("dueDate").value);
  var z = parseInt((currentDate - dueDate) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

  alert(`overdue by:  ${z} days`);
}
```

```html
<form name = "myForm" method = "POST" action = "form.html">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Book Returning Due Date:  </td>
      <td><input type = "date" name = "due_date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" id = "dueDate" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Current Date:  </td>
      <td><input type = "date" name = "current_date" placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" id = "currentDate" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class = "button-1" type="button" name = "due_fine" value = "Check for Due" onclick = "Fine();" /> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input class = "button-2" type = "reset" value = "Reset">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the edition @hassan-imam. Btw, I've fixed the code :)

Comment: @hash_hw That's great.